# How to put list of dates in JComboBox in 'dd-mm-yyyy' and also in 'yyyy-yyyy' format SWING?

Tags: java, swing, date, datetime, netbeans-8

I want to create a window and put on it a:

1. box that you can insert your birth date in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format
2. box that you can put your studying year in 'yyyy-yyyy' format

But I don't know if I should do a combo box and put all the date or there is a solution like a type of box that has 'dd-mm-yyyy' format and another type of box that have 'yyyy-yyyy' format.
USING SWING

Comment: You don't say whether you're using Swing or JavaFX.  Assuming Swing, you can use a [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) to input either date format.

Comment: i'm  using Swing

Answer (score 0):

For the birth date use a date picker. Make sure to use one that supports java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for example [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) (I haven’t got experience with it).

For the years of study you may want two boxes, one for picking the start year and one for the end year. Once the start year has been chosen, you may fill the other one with only the years from the start year until today.